# With ESLint, how would you require a `return` after a `res.[...].send({...})`?

Tags: node.js, express, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-eslint

We have a few controllers that were written in a way that allows the `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]` error to be sent.

For context this happens in code similar to...
*This is a **very** contrived example*

```
try{
  if(someCheck) { res.status(400).send({someStatus}); }
  /* other code */
}catch(e){ res.status(500).send({error}); }
```

In the example above if the `someCheck` causes the 400 to be sent and then the "other code" triggers an exception we would receive the headers sent error as mentioned.

My question to help mitigate this...
Is there an eslint rule or could a custom rule be created that would require either...

```
return res.status(400).send({someStatus});
/* or */
res.status(400).send({someStatus});
return;
```

I'd prefer the later, but really the goal is to warn/error if `send()` is called and doesn't have a correlated return statement.

Comment: Sounds like your `try/catch` blocks are not scoped properly. Of course you can write a custom ESLint rule, but should you, or should you refactor your `try/catch` blocks?

Comment: Please show us a try/catch block that would actually have the problem you describe.  The one you show would not cause that error as `return` is not required in either of what you show (without seeing more context around it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool I'm working on: [**Putout**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout).

So if you have code like this:

```js
function abc() {
    try{
      if(someCheck) { res.status(400).send({someStatus}); }
      /* other code */
    }catch(e){ res.status(500).send({error}); }
    
    res.status(200).send();
    return res.status(200).send(success);
}
```

Just use [Replacer](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/engine-runner#replacer) ([playground](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/1eb14229624ff4a3e58b187d5e907efd/2b8fd7327105ab61a49d64dbaa8d33c4d955aa0d)):

```js
export const report = () => `Use 'return' when calling '.send()'`;

const isReturn = (path) => path.parentPath.isReturnStatement();
const noReturn = (vars, path) => !isReturn(path);
const addReturn = (vars, path) => ReturnStatement(path.parentPath.node.expression);

export const match = () => ({
    '__a.send()': noReturn,
    '__a.send(__b)': noReturn,
});

export const replace = () => ({
    '__a.send()': addReturn,
    '__a.send(__b)': addReturn,
});
```

And you will have code like this:

```js
function abc() {
  try{
    if(someCheck) {
      return res.status(400).send({someStatus});
    }
    /* other code */
  }catch(e){
    return res.status(500).send({error});
  }

  return res.status(200).send();
  return res.status(200).send(success);
}
```

It checks if `__.send()` used without `ReturnStatement` with help of [**PutoutScript**](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/blob/master/docs/putout-script.md) and pattern [`__a`](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/blob/master/docs/putout-script.md#__a) - linked value that means any Expression.

To run the plugin by ESLint, use [eslint-plugin-putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-putout#readme).

This is the simplest way, because there is (almost) no need to deal with `AST`. Anyways you should remember that [`ReturnStatement`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types#returnstatement) has one `argument`, and according to [Babel Handbook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md) to access parent path so called `.parentPath` should be used. And we access `.expression` property because [`CallExpression`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types#callexpression) `__.send(__)` should be always wrapped by [`Statement`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types#statement), [`ExpressionStatement`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types#expressionstatement) in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You just need modify the eslint rule on eslint config, or you can modify your code like this

```js
function abc() {
  let someStatus;
  let status;
  try{
    if(someCheck) {
      status = 400;
      someStatus = 'Bad Request';
    }
    /* other code */
  }catch(e){
    status = 500;
    someStatus = 'Internal Server Error';
  }

  return res.status(status).send(someStatus);
}
```